# Magento 2.3 : How to attach csv file in email?

Tags: magento2.3, email, attachment

How do we send email with attachments in magento 2 ? 
And file type be like .csv

Previously it was working when we were in 2.2x but after been upgrading to 2.3 it causing issues in attachments. And we did tried [this extension](https://github.com/extait-com/email-attachment)  as well but they are writing in a text file.

Expected Result :
               Load the file from the local path from module directory  and attach it with email in M2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this below code in your helper:

```
<?php

namespace RH\MailSystem\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
    * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
    */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\Factory
     */
    protected $templateFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File
     */
    protected $reader;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\Factory $templateFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File $reader,
    ){
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->reader = $reader;
    }


    public function sendMailtoSupport($subject, $message, $allfileatt)
    {
        try {
            $email_template = "your_email_templpate_id";
            $mail_to = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE); // sender email id
            $emailTemplateVariables['message'] = $message;
            $emailTemplateVariables['tempsubject'] = $subject;
            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($emailTemplateVariables);
            $zendTransport = $this->getEmailConfiguration();
            //Create email
            $senderName = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE); // sender name
            $senderEmail = $mail_to;
            $sendToEmail = $mail_to;
            $mail = new \Zend_Mail();
            $mail->setFrom($senderEmail, $senderName);
            $mail->addTo($sendToEmail);

            /**
             * Mail Attachement Code
             */
            foreach ($allfileatt as $value) {
                if ($value['fileName'] != "") {
                    $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                    $filePath = $mediaUrl . "ticketsystem/attachment/" . $value['new_fileName'];
                    $fileContent = $this->reader->fileGetContents($filePath);
                    $mail->createAttachment(
                        $fileContent,
                        \Zend_Mime::TYPE_OCTETSTREAM,
                        \Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
                        \Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64,
                        $value['fileName']
                    );
                }
            }
            $mail->setSubject($subject);
            $templateOptions = [
                'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
            ];
            $htmlBody = $this->templateFactory->get($email_template, $this->templateModel)
                ->setVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setOptions($templateOptions)
                ->processTemplate();
            $mail->setBodyHtml($htmlBody);
            $mail->send($zendTransport);
            /*send attachment*/

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function getEmailConfiguration()
    {
        $username = $this->getEmailConfig('username');
        $password = $this->getEmailConfig('password');
        $auth = strtolower($this->getEmailConfig('auth'));
        $smtpHost = $this->getEmailConfig('smtphost');
        $smtpConf = [
            'name' => $this->getEmailConfig('name'),
            'port' => $this->getEmailConfig('smtpport'),
        ];
        if ($auth != 'none') {
            $smtpConf['auth'] = $auth;
            $smtpConf['username'] = $username;
            $smtpConf['password'] = $password;
        }
        $ssl = $this->getEmailConfig('ssl');
        if ($ssl != 'none') {
            $smtpConf['ssl'] = $ssl;
        }
        $transport = new \Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp($smtpHost, $smtpConf);
        return $transport;
    }

    private function getEmailConfig($key)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('system/gmailsmtpapp/' . $key,\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        // Return your SMTP configs value
    }
}
```

Now, call ***sendMailtoSupport()*** function with parameters from where you want to send.

[image]

I hope it will helpful for you.

Comment: In this, you need to pass array of current file name and new file name.

Comment: Like : [
                            'new_fileName' => $new_fileName,
                            'fileName' => $fileName,
                        ];

Comment: Yes. You need to modify as per your SMTP extension. Which extension you used? I will attach screenshot.

Comment: I added screenshot. You can check it and get reference from it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96014/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-prathap-gunasekaran).

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: Can you share complete code of this extension ? or kindly answer on this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351897/send-custom-csv-file-on-email-after-every-24-hours-in-magento-2